# Why is Poltergeist not registered as a driver for Capybara when used with Guard/Konacha?

Tags: selenium, capybara, guard, poltergeist, konacha

I'm having trouble using Poltergeist as the driver for Capybara in Konacha tests run with Guard.

I have the following in config/initializers/konacha.rb:

```
Konacha.configure do |config|
  require 'capybara/poltergeist'
  config.spec_dir     = "spec/javascripts"
  config.spec_matcher = /_spec\.|_test\./
  config.driver       = :poltergeist
  config.stylesheets  = %w(manifest_public)
end if defined?(Konacha)
```

My tests run successfully in Poltergeist with `bundle exec rake konacha:run`

However, when I use the following Guardfile:

```
guard :konacha, driver: :poltergeist do
  watch(%r{^app/assets/javascripts/(.*)\.js(\.coffee)?$}) { |m| "#{m[1]}_spec.js" }
  watch(%r{^spec/javascripts/.+_spec(\.js|\.js\.coffee)$})
end
```

Guard complains while starting Konacha:

> 14:18:05 - INFO - Starting Konacha
>
> 14:18:05 - ERROR -Capybara::DriverNotFoundError: no driver called :poltergeist was found, available drivers: :rack_test, :selenium>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution which works, but it seems a little hacky, so if anyone wants to suggest something better I'm all ears. I realized that the Konacha initializer is not being loaded until after Guard loads Konacha, so I had to replicate the registration of the `Capybara::Poltergeist` driver in the Guardfile:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {:js_errors => true})
end

guard :konacha, driver: :poltergeist do
  watch(%r{^app/assets/javascripts/(.*)\.js(\.coffee)?$}) { |m| "#{m[1]}_spec.js" }
  watch(%r{^spec/javascripts/.+_spec(\.js|\.js\.coffee)$})
end
```